# Google Scripts - keep track of element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've got a .gs file, which uses `body.findText("mytext")` to get an element. This is ran when the user clicks *button 1*.

To my javascript, I return a piece of html, like such:

```html
<button onclick="highlightText(`mytext`)">highlight</button>"
```

We'll call this *button 2*.

Once *button 2* is clicked, I search for the first occurance of `mytext` and highlight it.

Now a problem comes in when the user starts editing the document. If he adds another instance of `mytext` before the one that was found at first, that one will be highlighted. What I want is that the one that I found when *button 1* was clicked to be highlighted.

How do I keep track of the exact element, as found when *button 1* was clicked, no matter how the document changes?

What I've attempted:

- Serialize the element (JSON.stringify), gives {}. (Hoped for something of an UUID or so.)
- Keep track based on index, index can change if something is added before this text.
- Simply search for the same text again, but as described above this gives problems when the user adds the same text again.
- Looked into storing a reference in document properties, but then I'd still need serialization.
- Thought about adding hidden elements with a GUID of my own, but can't find a way to do that.

Comment: You may need to use this [findText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern,-from)

Comment: @Cooper Could you elaborate how using the version with ```from``` parameter woud help me?

Comment: It's similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Yes, so I could get an exact index. I know that. But of course an exact index won't help if an element/sentence is inserted before the current one, as the index won't point to the same sentence any more.

Comment: Try using bookmarks then.

Comment: I've ran into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321127/caching-selected-text-element-with-google-doc-apps-script, so marking this as duplicate.

Comment: @iansedano That's the link I posted right above your comment.

Comment: It was an auto generated comment that was added after I added my vote to the duplicate flag. Sorry, should have remembered and deleted it